# Role based authentication for different roles of user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel 5.5 where i'm developing **Role Based Authentication** for users.
The system user can have multiple roles and those roles can have access to multiple menus. 
I want to check if hte current roles of the user have access of particular menu.

Following is my table structure

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('deleted_at')->nullable(); 
    });

     Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->longText('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('deleted_at')->nullable(); 
    });

      Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->integer('is_default')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('deleted_at')->nullable(); 

        $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('action')->unique();
        $table->integer('sequence');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('deleted_at')->nullable(); 
    });

    Schema::create('menu_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('menu_id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('deleted_at')->nullable(); 


        $table->foreign('menu_id')
                ->references('id')->on('menus')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I've defined relationship as follow :

User.php

```php
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Role.php

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function menus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Menu::class);
}
```

How can i check if specific role has access of specific menu?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Erubiel I have added menu and menu_role schema. Please check

Comment: i copied and modified previous code of mine... it was the same pattern but with a permissions table... maybe some ids or tables are wrong but the main general idea, works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for this in User and in Role... i would do it in User Model

Something like this should work in user model... for Role, just remove user related tables.

```php
public function checkMenuPermission($key)
{

    // YOUR KEY can be name, id, any unique column... 

    $results = DB::table('users')
                    ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                    ->join('menu_roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'menu_roles.role_id')
                    ->join('menus', 'menus.id', '=', 'menu_roles.menu_id')
                    ->select('menus.name')
                    ->where('users.id', $this->id)
                    ->where('menus.name', $key)
                    ->orderBy('menus.name')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get()->count();

    return $results > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Then in your controllers just can just call it like `$user->checkMenuPermission('someSome');`

**Edit**

If you want to do it just with **Eloquent** you can

```js
public function checkMenuPermission($key){
    foreach($this->menus as $m){
      if($m->name == $key){
         return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: With query its is possible, i want to try with laravel way using relationships. Is it possible with it?

Comment: I edited the post according to your needs... think that might work.

Comment: I guess query will be better in this scenario, because there can be multiple menus so instead of looping through each menu, query will give fast response. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable like `$menuId` you could simply use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) with the authenticated user and check if the relationships exist:

```
$canAccess = auth()->user()->whereHas('roles.menus', function ($query) use($menuId) {

    $query->where('id', $menuId);

})->exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how policies work ?
It should help you a lot in this case. 
E.G : You can create a MenuPolicy file where you put all your restrictions/authorazitions logic for the menu
And then simply use *@can* directive in the blade file of the menu according to your policies

Check there 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies

Answer (score -1):

You have to create another pivot table, something like

```
Schema::create('role_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('menu_id');
    $table->integer('role_id');

    $table->foreign('menu_id')
            ->references('id')->on('menus')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Obviously, there must be a `menus` table.

Than a lot of possibilities opens up... I think the better way is creating a middleware that can be used for the specific menu's routes.

For example:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Check user roles in order to check if role has access to the menu
    foreach($request->user()->roles as $role) {
        // This code supposes that your route is something like http://app.tld/menus/{menu_id}
        if($role->menus()->find($request->route('menu_id'))) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    // Otherwise abort, redirect.. whatever
    abort(401);
}
```